# How can I freeze part of object while applying simple deform(twist)?

Tags: modifiers

As the [Axis, Origin] is set to the Hemi lamp, the whole body twist along the lamp (upper image)

What I really want is to keep the feet freeze while applying the twist.(like lower image)

Is it possible?

thanks.

[image]
[image]

After using vertex group, the lower body is freeze.
But the weight paint not working well.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe using vertex groups/weight painting would be the best way to accomplish this. In the screenshot below the selected vertices are added to a vertex group and plugged into the deform modifier:

[image]

Keep in mind that with weight painting, you can also have areas that are only partly influenced: (more flexibility)

[image]

Lastly, there are tons of resources on the web about vertex groups, here is one [link to the blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html).

Comment: thank you for your help. Now I can freeze the lower body. But even with weight painting, the twist still not working as I want. Adding empty can help?